# How to unit test WinForms with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I added from Tools | Extensions and Updates: NUnit Test Adapter, NUnit Test Generator, xUnit.net runner for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, Unit Test Generator.

Only Unit Test Generator seems to give me a context menu item that allows me to right-click a form's class constructor and "Generate Unit Test".  However, that context menu item does not appear when I right-click a method of a plain old class in the same project.  That context method also does not appear if I try to generate unit tests for a button click or textbox selection, including if I try it from anywhere inside the code of the Form Designer code (e.g. `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);`). Why is that?

Also, while "Generate Unit Test" gives me a choice of MSTest, NUnit and XUnit, only MSTest works.  The other two choices create the new test project but not the test class and generate a long error messagebox:

> No exports were found that match the constraint:
>
> ContractName
>
> NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices
>
> RequiredTypeIdentity
>
> NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices

Finally, the skeleton MSTest method generated shows no obvious way to access the form and its controls.  The author of this article http://www.steveandrews.me/blog/2008/02/05/testing-the-winforms-ui, obviously using a different Visual Studio back in 2008, writes that the generated method includes code that helpfully provides access to the form:

```
`[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("WindowsFormsApplication1.exe")]
public void InitializeComponentTest()
{
    Form1_Accessor target = new Form1_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    target.InitializeComponent();
    Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
}`
```

Now, with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and MSTest, all I get is:

`[TestMethod()]
        public void Form1Test()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`

I read elsewhere that one should use the MVVM pattern instead if one wants to test things like textbox selections and button clicks, etc but I want to know if there is a "proper" way to unit test classic WinForms from inside Visual Studio.  (I'm obviously new to all this!)

Thank you

Comment: I don't have the choice unfortunately.

However, I did answer one of my own questions. I noticed that my plain old class wasn't declared public so I did and now the "Generate Unit Test" right-click menu item appears for it. That's the problem with the eventhandlers, etc, too. They're private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing private methods is a bad practice, as is making the classes internal and using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute so that you can test it.

Basically, if you have a private method, that method represents an implementation detail of your class -- what that method does is irrelevant to your testing efforts. What you **should** be testing is the public API of your class.

"Well, I want to test some logic that's buried deep in a private method, but it's really hard to pass data in to my public API that hits all of the logic in my private methods!", you might be saying. That is a common response to the advice I just gave, and there's an answer:

Logic that's hard to test via the public API is generally an indicator that your class is poorly designed. You'll want to start to decompose the class into multiple, smaller classes and test each of *those* classes through *their* public API.

Now, one last thing: You're trying to test Windows Forms. WinForms is ancient and does not make even a cursory attempt to guide you down the path of using modern patterns and practices, like separation of concerns. That means you generally have a lot of view logic mixed in with your business logic, which makes it harder to unit test. You can look into starting to implement the MVP pattern.

Comment: This is good advice, I have just started work on an old legacy win-forms app that was translated from vb6 to c#. We have implemented an MVC type architecture for the new stuff, however after consideration It would have been more suitable to do MVP, either way it has made  a large difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `Accessor`s that are used in there were deprecated and are not included in VS2012 onwards.

You cannot access privates any more.

What you can do is make your classes internal and use the [`InternalsVisibleTo` Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to enable your unit test assembly to access them.